# Android - startActivityForResult to get users location?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-location

Is it possible to start a default map activity so that user can share his current location, and receive this location coordinates via onActivityResult()?

I'm writing a messaging app, and I would like to give users ability to attach their current location (or nearest address, or nearest business).  I know that Maps app has the ability to share location, but I want to launch it from my app via Intent centering the initial view on current position, then have the user position/move the marker and return its coordinates to my app.

I don't want to write my own map view activity, only start/show already installed default maps app that usually comes pre-installed on all phones/tablets.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to start a default map activity so that user can share his current location, and receive this location coordinates via onActivityResult()?

There is no standard `Intent` action for just generically opening a map on nothing in particular, though I suppose you could try `ACTION_VIEW` on a `geo:` `Uri` with no actual latitude and longitude.

However, you cannot get a location back from it. The map application will not know if you have the permission to know the user's location, and `ACTION_VIEW` is not designed for use with `startActivityForResult()`.